# @onetoMany with @JoinTable does not save the entiity with mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I Have data model like below.

**variant table:**

id(variantId) , status

**associaiton table:**

id(associaitonId) , status

**variant_association table: maintains the one to many mapping**

id, fk_variant_id, fk_association_id

1. When I pull a variant by variantId I can see the respective list of
   AssociationEntity is also being pulled. Relationship is managed in the third join table(variant_association).
2. But when I try to save a VariantEntity with list of AssociationEntity in it I see the below error.

> ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [SqlExceptionHelper.java:146]
>   - Column 'fk_association_id' cannot be null
>       2017-09-18 14:19:50.390 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-8] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [SqlExceptionHelper.java:233] -
>   Column 'fk_association_id' cannot be null

Variant entity mapping:

```
    public class VariantEntity
    {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String status;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable
            (
                name="variant_association",
                joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="fk_variant_id", referencedColumnName="id" , nullable=false) },
                inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="fk_association_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, nullable=false) }
            )
        private List<AssociationEntity> associations;

    }

    public class AssociationEntity
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable
            (
                    name="variant_association",
                    joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="fk_association_id", referencedColumnName="id" , nullable=false) },
                    inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="fk_variant_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) }
            )
    private VariantEntity variant;

    }
```

Does any one has any idea on what i might be doing worng here?

Comment: Can you add the AssociationEntity?

Comment: Added the AssociaitonEntity. Do I need to add an annotation to AssociaitonEntity? @fhossfel

Comment: can you please add the code you use to insert